# HighlightGraph doesn't work for NearestNeighborGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Why doesn't this work?

```
SeedRandom[1]
HighlightGraph[NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}], 2], 1, VertexSize -> 1/2, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Check out the `VertexList` of the graph. You'll need to use `IndexGraph` before referring the vertices as integers.

Comment: @ChipHurst Makes sense. I mean, it doesn't, but it works. Care to make it an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I think it makes sense. Per the docs, the second argument refers to explicit parts of the graph, not an index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vertices of the graph are not integers:

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}], 2];

VertexList[g]
```

> ```
> {{0.614608, 0.952102}, {0.116343, 0.82104}, ...}
> ```

We can reindex the vertices to run through consecutive integers:

```
HighlightGraph[IndexGraph[g], 1, VertexSize -> 1/2, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Alternatively we can pass in the explicit vertex:

```
HighlightGraph[g, VertexList[g][[1]], VertexSize -> 1/2, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]