# Can not customize `VertexLabels` of `NearestNeighborGraph`

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the following code:

```
flagAsia = Rasterize /@(Ctrl+=  Asia flags) (* get the Asia flags with free form input *)

NearestNeighborGraph[flagAsia, 2, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> ImageResize[flagAsia[[i]], 70], {i, 1, Length@flagAsia}]]
```

With `VertexLabels -> Table[i -> ImageResize[flagAsia[[i]], 70], {i, 1, Length@flagAsia}]`, I meant to label the graph with flag icon. But this command seems not evaluated.

What is the problem?

Platform: `Ubuntu 19.04`, `Mathematica 12.1`

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216891/highlightgraph-doesnt-work-for-nearestneighborgraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments by Chip Hurst, see [this answer by Chip](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216898/125) re why your code does not work.

An alternative way to use `NearestNeighborGraph` with country flags as vertex labels and geo-positions as vertex coordinates:

```
countries = EntityList @ EntityClass["Country", "Asia"]; 

resizedflags = Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> 30, ImageResolution -> 100, 
    Background -> None] & /@ EntityValue[countries, "FlagImage", "EntityAssociation"];

vlabels = Normal[KeyValueMap[# -> Placed[{CanonicalName@# , #2}, {Tooltip, Center}] &]@
    resizedflags];

vcoords = Normal[(Reverse@*First) /@  
    EntityValue[countries, "Position", "EntityAssociation"]]; 

NearestNeighborGraph[countries, 2, 
 VertexLabels -> vlabels, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have got the key points: (1) the element is not integer `i`; (2) turn to `VertexLabels` and `VertexCoordinates` to compose the graph.